# Can I check that verification message was delivered in Twilio Verify?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on an MFA implementation with Twilio Verify and a C# library in my pet project. So, the question is, can I verify that the message was delivered? There are strange cases when I try to send a message, I don't get any exceptions, but the message delivery status is unknown, and I don't get it on my mobile phone. Here is an example:

[image: Image with delivery status is Unknown]

I found a solution using webhook, but it fits very poorly into the current architecture of the project. So I wanted to know if there is any way to get records about the messages which are shown in Verify service logs and check their delivery status with something like a simple API call.

Comment: There is no way, to my knowledge, to look up the message status of a message sent by the Verify API. Is there anything about the numbers you are trying to send to that may cause these unknown statuses as that shouldn't happen. You might find your best bet is to send the message Sids of the unknown messages to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will be able to look into the reasons for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you created a verification you can [fetch the verification](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#fetch-a-verification) using:

```
curl -X GET 'https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications/VEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

The response includes a `status` and a `carrier` section with potential error codes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `carrier` field in response still provides no errors (It shows null) when message status is unknown/queued. And verification's `status` field doesn't solve the issue because it is related to the verification process, not message delivery.

Comment: What does `send_code_attempts` yield in your specific case? You could try to fetch the most recent messages from your account and see if you find the token send attempt and inspect it, see [Read multiple Message resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources).

Comment: `send_code_attempts` contains three fields: `attemptSid` which begins with VLXXXX, `channel` and `time`. None of them can help me understand if the message was delivered in that attempt or not. 
Is there any way to fetch messages from Verify? I tried to read messages but I receive no messages from Verify. Also when I open https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/dashboard I see my Verify messages on the chart but I don't see them in Message logs.